# How to solve this system of linear equations using Gaussian elimination?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, gaussian-elimination

I'm having trouble with this problem from my linear algebra course. The problem is:

> A new restaurant owner decides to have 20 tables for her guests, a certain number of tables with space for 4 people, some with space for 6 people and also one or more tables with space for 8 guests. In total, there are 108 seats available, but if only half of the seats at the 4-tables and 6-tables, and only a quarter of the seats at the 8-tables, are occupied, the restaurant will have 46 guests. How many tables with space for 4, 6 and 8 seats does she need to set up in her premises?

I tried to solve it by writing the system of equations as a matrix:

$$\left( \begin{array}{cccc}
1&1&1&20\\ 
2&3&2&46\\ 
4&6&8&108
\end{array} \right)
$$

Then I applied Gaussian elimination by doing the following steps:

- Subtracting 2 times the first row from the second row
- Swapping the first and third rows
- Multiplying the first row by 1/4
- Subtracting the second row from the third row
- Subtracting 2/3 times the second row from the first row
- Subtracting 2 times the third row from the first row
- Adding the first row to the third row

This gave me the following matrix:

$$
\left( \begin{array}{cccc}
-1&0&0&-\frac{5}{2} \\ 
0&1&0&6\\ 
0&0&1&\frac{23}{2} 
\end{array} \right)
$$

However, this does not match the answer given in the textbook, which is:

$$
\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 10 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 6 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 4
\end{array}\right)
$$

Can someone please explain where I went wrong and how to get the correct answer? I appreciate any help or hints. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Starting from
$$\left( \begin{array}{cccc}
1&1&1&20\\ 
2&3&2&46\\ 
4&6&8&108
\end{array} \right)$$
after the fourth step in your list we get
$$\left( \begin{array}{cccc}
1&3/2&2&27\\ 
0&1&0&6\\ 
1&0&1&14
\end{array} \right).$$
Now we subtract $\large\color{red}{3/2}$ times the second row from the first row
$$\left( \begin{array}{cccc}
1&0&2&18\\ 
0&1&0&6\\ 
1&0&1&14
\end{array} \right).$$
From here, subtracting the third row from the first row and
then subtracting the first row from the third row, we obtain
$$\left( \begin{array}{cccc}
0&0&1&4\\ 
0&1&0&6\\ 
1&0&0&10
\end{array} \right).$$
Finally, after swapping the first and the third row, we get
$$\left( \begin{array}{cccc}
1&0&0&10\\
0&1&0&6\\ 
0&0&1&4
\end{array} \right).$$

Answer (score 2):

A step by step approach.

It is very slow to build but very good in that you can go back to a step and fix things.

Notice that the operation appears besides the row so you know which row was affected exactly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simply do the following transformations (R means Row)

R2 becomes R2-2R1

R3 becomes R3-4R1

$$\left( \begin{array}{cccc}
1&1&1&20\\ 
0&1&0&6\\ 
0&2&4&28
\end{array} \right)$$

R3 becomes (R3-2R2)/4

$$\left( \begin{array}{cccc}
1&1&1&20\\ 
0&1&0&6\\ 
0&0&1&4
\end{array} \right)$$

R1 becomes R1-R2-R3
$$\left( \begin{array}{cccc}
1&0&0&10\\ 
0&1&0&6\\ 
0&0&1&4
\end{array} \right)$$

I hope that helps. (In your solution, 2/3 and 3/2 are confused.)